# Importing files in subdirectories when using Yarn Workspaces and Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I'm having trouble porting a Yarn Workspaces monorepo to TypeScript. In the previous working version of the monorepo, `moduleA` could import something from a subdirectory of `moduleB`.

The new ported code attempts the same thing...

```js
/* monorepo/packages/moduleA/src/helpers/misc.ts */

export const someHelper = () => console.log('hello world')
```

```js
/* monorepo/packages/moduleB/src/index.ts */

import {someHelper} from 'moduleA/src/helpers/index.js'
```

This yields the error:

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'monorepo/node_modules/moduleA/src/helpers/misc.js' imported from monorepo/packages/moduleB/lib/index.js

My TsConfig for both packages:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "composite": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "es6"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
}
```

And added config for the `moduleB` package:

```json
"references": [
  {
    "path": "../moduleA"
  }
]
```

Note that I am building `moduleB` with `tsc --build`.

One way to solve the issue would be to simply export everything I need from `moduleA` as named exports in the entry point of the module. The reason I don't want to do this is because they may not be needed in the corresponding distribution which gets built from various parts of the monorepo. Importing and exporting them in `moduleA` would mean bundling code and sometimes running code that didn't need to be run, or shouldn't be run due to the environment.

Another thing to note is that if I rename `monorepo/packages/moduleA/src/helpers/misc.ts` with a `.js` extension instead of typescript; it works.

I can also seemingly change the error by adding this to the "compilerOptions" in `moduleB`:

```json
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "moduleA/helpers/*": ["../moduleA/src/helpers/*"]
},
```

And changing the import statement to:

```js
/* monorepo/packages/moduleB/src/index.ts */

import {someHelper} from 'moduleA/helpers/index.js'
```

But this gives me a type definition error:

> src/index.ts:2:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moduleA/helpers/misc.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

Perhaps the above use of the `paths` in the TsConfig is not the way to go.

To summarise, the ultimate goal here is to allow importing of any of the files from `moduleA`'s subdirectories to use in `moduleB`, without having to publish a separate module for that purpose.